# Get the image source of a picture without knowing the URL in C#?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, image, zooming

I'm working on an ASP.NET page where you can zoom in on the pictures displayed in a catalog.

The catalog loads images from a file, so I will not know what the URLs will be before the page loads. What I want to do is get the URL from the clicked picture and then use that to fill an image control on the same page.

This is what I have:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ImageButton pic = new ImageButton();
    pic.ImageUrl = "Pictures/" + Main.pics[i];
    pic.Height = 200;
    pic.Width = 200;
    pic.ToolTip = "Click to Zoom";
    pic.Style["cursor"] = "zoom-in";
    pic.Click += ImageZoom_Click;

    cell.Controls.Add(pic);
}

public void ImageZoom_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ImageButton imgBtn = new ImageButton();
    ZoomedImage.ImageUrl = imgBtn.ImageUrl;
    ZoomedImage.Visible = true;
}
```

It has no errors but of course the picture does not show up, just the border ("empty image") where it's supposed to be. I have seen some things in JavaScript but I'm unsure of the C# syntax.

I want to just be able to say "The URL of ZoomedImage = The URL of the image I just clicked" but of course, life isn't that simple.

This is the image control code, if that helps:

```
<asp:Image ID="ZoomedImage" CssClass="ZoomedImage"
style="height: 500px; width: 470px;" runat="server" Visible="False" />
```

Thanks so much! :)

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this

```
 public void img_click(object s, EventArgs e)
    {
        ImageButton img = new ImageButton();
        img = s as ImageButton;
        img2.ImageUrl = img.ImageUrl;
    }
you need to get the image button that was clicked, which is really your only problem.
```